# DbContext was changed error on WCF project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, startup

Dears
In my solution I have projects layered with few class librarys and two projects (WcfUI and MvcUI).
I spend 99% of time for MvcUI. however WcfUI is using the same database and services for backend.
Using generic repository pattern and entity framework I can use the same DbContext written once for both WCF and MVC.
Problem appears when I create new DbSet and add a migration.
Mvc is published after few changes but Wcf not because last updates didnt touch it's logic.

Do I have to always publish both - Mvc and Wcf to avoid "Database model/context was changed..." error

Or is it good practice for Wcf to put in App_Start new class like below:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WcfUI.App_Start.DbInitialization), "Start")]

namespace WcfUI.App_Start
{
    using DAL.Database.DbContexts;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    /// <summary>
    /// To Avoid EF error: model was changed since bla bla...
    /// </summary>
    public static class DbInitialization
    {
        public static void Start() => Database.SetInitializer<MvcDbContext>(null); 
    }
}
```

At this moment I am using this class and problem seems solved but I'm not quite sure if it's a proper solution?

Comment: *Do I have to always publish both* - yes. What if you make a db change that breaks the other application?

Comment: Well.. it will crash anyway :)